# C++ objects within an array inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes (TypeA, and TypeB) where TypeB extends TypeA.

If I create an object like so:

`ATypeA* NewObject = SpawnObject<ATypeB>();`

the Spawn object method just creates a new ATypeB object

and then store it in an array of TypeA, is the object within the array of TypeA or TypeB?

Comment: it will be from TypeA

Comment: Do you store the object or the pointer in the array?

Comment: You only get polymorphism with pointers and references. When you assign to a regular variable, you just get the slice with that class.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your array and how you assign the object.

If the array is declared as `TypeA myArray[10];` and you assign your object using `myArray[0] = *NewObject;` then the object in the array will be a *sliced* copy of `*NewObject` of type `TypeA`.

If the array is declared as `TypeA* myArray[10];` (probably your intention) and you assign your object using `myArray[0] = NewObject;` then the array will contain a *pointer* to the same object pointed by `NewObject`, of course of type `TypeB`.

That said, you should probably consider using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TypeA>>` rather than a raw array. It will make your code simpler and safer.